# How can i add buttons afterly in Discord.py?

Tags: python, class, discord.py

I am making a Discord bot for an order. And I need to make a role giver button list and add buttons to the first message after with a command I trying this for 2 days but I can't add buttons only edit the first message

My code is:

```
class RolButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, rol_name):
        global a
        a = role_name
        super().__init__(label=rol_name, style=ButtonStyle.green)

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        author = interaction.user
        
        role = discord.utils.get(author.guild.roles, name=a)
        if role in author.roles:
            await author.remove_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"you dropped {role} role", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await author.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"You take {role} role", ephemeral=True)

@Bot.command()
async def role(ctx, *args):
    args = str(args).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("', '", " ").replace("'", "")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    button = RolButton(args)
    view = MyView()
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name=args)
    view.add_item(button)
    embed = Embed(
        title="Take roles",
        description="Click buttons you want"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

@Bot.command()
async def rolekle(ctx, *args):
    args = str(args).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("', '", " ").replace("'", "")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    button = RolButton(args)
    view = MyView()
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name=args)
    view.add_item(button)
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
        await message.edit(view=view)
```

How can I add buttons after with command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a button to a message and want to keep the ones that already exist, you need to reuse the existing view or create a new one with the same components:

```py
class RolButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, rol_name):
        super().__init__(label=rol_name, style=ButtonStyle.green)

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        author = interaction.user
        
        role = discord.utils.get(author.guild.roles, name=self.label)
        if role in author.roles:
            await author.remove_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"you dropped {role} role", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await author.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"You take {role} role", ephemeral=True)


@bot.command()
async def rolekle(ctx, *args):
    # args is a list of arguments, do not convert it to string, this is very ugly
    guild = ctx.guild
    new_role = await guild.create_role(name=args[0])
    # delete command message
    await ctx.message.delete()
    view = MyView()
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
        for row in message.components:
            for button in row.children: 
                view.add_item(RolButton(button.label))
        view.add_item(RolButton(new_role.name))
        await message.edit(view=view)
```

Comment: Thanks for to reply. But when i trying to command i get ```  File "c:\main.py", line 66, in rolekle
    view.add_item(RolButton(component.label))
AttributeError: 'ActionRow' object has no attribute 'label'``` error. I search how can i fix this, but i didn't.

Comment: Updated the code fixing this problem

Comment: I apologise for my incompetence. But i have TypeError: 'ActionRow' object is not iterable error now.

Comment: Updated the code fixing this problem

Comment: Iam really stupid, how can i didn't think this. Thank you too much, you're a lifesaver!